# Version of font doesn't appear in editing programs

Tags: windows-8, fonts

Installed [these](http://fontfabric.com/lovelo-font/) fonts and in all my programs (word, photoshop, after effects, etc.) only the Line Bold and Regular appear. The Light version of the font is somehow missing. (Which is the one I wanted)

I am sure the font is installed and I have tried to install it again but it says it is already installed. Using windows 8

Thank you for helping.

Comment: Try to uninstall it then install it again, using the proper Font folder dialog.

Comment: Good idea. But this is even weirder. I can only see the regular one in my folder. Not even the Line Bold which I can see in my programs. The line Light is not visible anywhere

Answer (score 0):

The fonts appear to have properties set that make only one at a time appear in Windows. If you delete one another will then become visible. So to get the Light version delete the other versions.